John 1:18: If no man has ever seen God, and Jesus is God, then how could any man have seen Jesus?
Exodus 33:20

But He added, “You cannot see My face, for no one can see Me and
live.”

John 1:18

No one has ever seen God, but the only begotten Son, who is at the
Father’s side, has revealed Him.

1 Timothy 6:16

He alone is immortal and dwells in unapproachable light. No one has
ever seen Him, nor can anyone see Him. To Him be honor and eternal
dominion! Amen.

John 6:46

No one has seen the Father except the one who is from God; only he has
seen the Father.

John 5:37-38

And the Father who sent Me has Himself testified about Me. You have
never heard His voice nor seen His form, nor does His word abide in
you, because you do not believe the One He sent.

1 John 4:12

No one has ever seen God; but if we love one another, God remains in
us, and His love is perfected in us.

If no man has ever seen or heard the Father God save the angels, then how could any man have seen or heard Christ if He is also God?
In the Old Testament, the Angel of the Lord was clearly the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ who is God's Son. God's Angel wields the Tetragrammaton as the divine agent and mediator between God and man.
Actually seeing the Angel of the Lord was like seeing God, because Christ is the exact imprint of God's nature as His image bearer despite not being God Himself.
This would perfectly explain how Jacob "saw God's face yet lived". Jacob did not actually see God's face; rather he "saw God" through divine agency, the revelation of God's Son who is the mediator between God and men (John 17:5) and the exact copy or imprint of the Father without actually being the Father who is Himself the one true God.
What are your thoughts? God bless everyone.

If you are going to pull verses out of context, you should at least be consistent in what can be stated from those verses. For example, you say, "If no man has seen or heard the Father God..." where do you find the term "Father God" in any of the verses you cite? Not one of these verses state the Father is God. Rather, you import a belief of what God is, then you equate that belief to the Father, then you ask how what you belief is the equation of Father God can be applied to Christ.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This top comment is left here to explain sentiment in the community of why this question is off topic. Though a question may include Bible text, questions are only on topic if they address the interpretation process, in most cases applied to specific text at least for examples. This question asks about the validity of conclusions after the interpretation process. That makes it off topic. Yes, it also makes many logical leaps in that process, which is why we close off-topic questions: because they often "bait" quibbling and logical leaps.

I also used to be a Unitarian but there is overwhelming scriptural evidence that supports the doctrine of Trinity. In the beginning God said, "Let us make man in our own image", this is the same exact reason that shows the title God refers to a collection of beings which include The Father, The Son and The Spirit. If God is One being then He would have said let me make man in my own image but this clearly shows that The Father participated in the creation process alongside other beings.
The phrase us means that God is plural and comprised of three beings with full awareness of each other . The statement to create is made by God the Father, The Word who is Jesus Christ makes another statement after Adam and Eve are fallen and uses the same phrase the Father used which is us
Genesis 3:22

Then the Lord God said, "Behold, the man has become like one of us

There is God and there is The Lord God, both use the phrase us which proves that God refers collectively to the three. They are three and they are united in their divine will.
The verse you cited doesn't invalidate that belief, no man has ever seen God which is subjective and means no man has ever seen The Father which is true because The Father dwells inside a light that cannot be approached, Only The Word who is the Lord Jesus Christ and God has made Him known
The greatest proof that Jesus Christ is Godis the introductory statement God used when he introduced Himself to Moses
Exodus 3:14

I am who I am

Then when Jesus was arguing with the Pharisees, he used the same phrase I Am
John 8:48-59

Before Abraham Was, I Am

But the verse that blows the lid wide open is the verse in Genesis where God refers to Himself as us, us shows a group, a collection of several beings and Jesus being one of them because John introduced Him as the word.
John 1:1

In the beginning was the Word(Jesus Christ) and The Word was with God(us) and the word was God

if God was just one being, God would have used the statement me.
Jesus Christ is not angel because the Word who is Jesus created and angels do not have the power to create
John 1:3

All things were made through Him, and without Him nothing was made that was made

The verse above shows the Lord God or the Word or Jesus Christ participated in creation as part of the Us, a power beyond the reach of angels

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

If they did not hear or see the Father because they did not believe the Son, what about those who believe the son and abide in Him.

And the Father who sent me has himself borne witness about me. His voice you have never heard, his form you have never seen, and you do not have his word abiding in you, for you do not believe the one whom he has sent.
(John 5:37–38, ESV)

See is used it two ways.  It can mean to understand:

Jesus answered them, “Truly, truly, I say to you, you are seeking me, not because you saw signs, but because you ate your fill of the loaves.
(John 6:26, ESV)

But obviously they physically saw the signs.  They just didn't understand their purpose.  How does one perceive the invisible?

For what can be known about God is plain to them, because God has shown it to them.  For his invisible attributes, namely, his eternal power and divine nature, have been clearly perceived, ever since the creation of the world, in the things that have been made.
(Romans 1:19–20, ESV)

Consider the context of John 1:18.  John has themes that run throughout his gospel.

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. ...
(John 1:1, ESV)


And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, and we have seen his glory, glory as of the only Son from the Father, full of grace and truth.
(John 1:14, ESV)


No one has ever seen God; the only God, who is at the Father’s side, he has made him known.
(John 1:18, ESV)


And whoever sees me sees him who sent me.
(John 12:45, ESV)


Jesus said to him, “Have I been with you so long, and you still do not know me, Philip? Whoever has seen me has seen the Father. How can you say, ‘Show us the Father’?"
(John 14:9, ESV)

John 1:14ff parallels Exodus:

And let them make me a sanctuary, that I may dwell in their midst.  Exactly as I show you concerning the pattern of the tabernacle, and of all its furniture, so you shall make it.
(Exodus 25:8–9, ESV)


The Presence of the LORD abode on Mount Sinai, and the cloud hid it for six days. On the seventh day He called to Moses from the midst of the cloud
(Exodus 24:16, JPS1985)


I will abide among the Israelites, and I will be their God. And they shall know that I the LORD am their God, who brought them out from the land of Egypt that I might abide among them, I the LORD their God.
(Exodus 29:45–46, JPS1985)


Moses could not enter the Tent of Meeting, because the cloud had settled [שָׁכַ֥ן same word translated dwell] upon it and the Presence of the LORD filled the Tabernacle.
(Exodus 40:35, JPS1985)


And let them make Me a sanctuary that I may dwell among them.
(Exodus 25:8, JPS1985)


I'm going to assume you're not suggesting a contradiction based on somehow a physical sight of the invisible God.  I am also going to assume that 'Father' and 'God' referring to the same person is an acceptable assumption.
So, with those assumptions, the New Testament has straight-forward answers.
Colossians 1:15a is perhaps the most concise.

He is the image of the invisible God.

So, one can see the image; one cannot see the invisible.
John 14:7-14 is really the answer to your question.  Jesus answers it himself.

7 If you had known Me, you would have known My Father also; from now
on you know Him, and have seen Him.”
8 Philip said to Him, “Lord, show us the Father, and it is enough for
us.” 9 Jesus said to him, “Have I been with you for so long a
time, and yet you have not come to know Me, Philip? The one who has
seen Me has seen the Father; how can you say, ‘Show us the Father’? 10
Do you not believe that I am in the Father, and the Father is in Me?
The words that I say to you I do not speak on My own, but the Father,
as He remains in Me, does His works. 11 Believe Me that I am in the
Father and the Father is in Me; otherwise believe because of the works
themselves. 12 Truly, truly I say to you, the one who believes in Me,
the works that I do, he will do also; and greater works than these he
will do; because I am going to the Father. 13 And whatever you ask in
My name, this I will do, so that the Father may be glorified in the
Son. 14 If you ask Me anything in My name, I will do it.

Basically, Jesus says that his works and teaching give clear evidence of the Father.  Seeing one is seeing the other.
The phrase, I am in the Father, and the Father is in Me really needs to be explained.  It's good Greek; it's far from anything remotely English.  In any case, it's a way of expressing a mutual and very close, interpersonal relationship.  Loosely, it means, "we're united in everything".  So, seeing the one is seeing the other.
There's also an interesting interplay in the text between οἶδα (to know) and γινώσκω (to know) which emphasizes the difference between factual knowledge (what I refer to as multiple-choice answers, and evidential knowledge.  The point of the interplay is to say that the person who has seen Jesus has seen the evidence that shows who the Father is.
Basically, if you know Jesus, you've seen the Father.

I generally agree with your opening statement with the following exceptions: Matt 1:23, John 1:1, John 1:18, 20:28, Acts 20:28, Rom 9:5, Phil 2:6, 2 Tim 2:2-6, Titus 2:13, Heb 1:8, 9, 2 Peter 1:1 - all refer to Jesus as "God".

@Dottard, what a nightmare you have there! 7 of your 11 verses are completely mistranslated. The other 4 are translated correctly but are misinterpreted. Some have removed punctuation, others have added words that are not there, some have removed words.

@JoshuaB - if you wish to debate/discuss the translations, then ask some questions and I (and others) will be happy to answer.

Dottard - John 1:1 says, "...and the Word was himself a god.", John 1:18 says, "...but the only begotten Son, who is at the Father's side, has revealed Him." Acts 20:28 says, "...which He purchased with the blood of His own." Rom 9:5 says, "...the Christ. God who us over all be blessed forever." Phil 2:6 says, "...form of a god... like a god...", Titus 2:13 says, "...the glory of our great God and Savior, Jesus Christ." Heb 1:8 says "...it says", 2 Peter 1:1 says, "...the righteousness of our God and Savior, Jesus Christ."

Dottard - As you can see, all 8 of those passages have been distorted by Trinitarian translator bias. The other 3 passages you mentioned are translated correctly are being misinterpreted. Matt 1:23 is saying that God is with us spiritually through Christ. John 20:28 was Thomas exclaiming that his risen Lord was standing before him by the power of his God; he was looking at the Father through the image of his Son. And I didn't see what you were getting at with 2 Tim 2:2-6.

@Dottard  You might not be being notified regarding Joshua B's statements, so here you are.  From my perspective, in this whole discussion, the difficulty is the dichotomy between the meaning of specific words (aka very detail oriented) and the transcendent, humanly-viewed, complex doctrine of the Trinity.  It's like in the story, Flatland, explaining three dimensions to a two dimensional creature.  The modus operandi doesn't fit the need.  That's why I pointed to John 14:7-14. One needs to grasp the meaning of that whole text for the light to go on.

@JoshuaB - I will not debate with you in this context except to note that you cannot justify your biased translations - i translated them directly from the Greek - did you? End of discussion.

Dottard, I did translate them from the Greek, without bias. I believe trinitarians translated then with bias.

@JoshuaB  Your translation of John 1:1, "...and the Word was himself a god." is translated with a pantheistic bias.  Why do I point this out?  Because it's verses like this that force one to either go down the road of pantheism or to Trinitarianism.  Accepting that the overwhelming context (the entire Bible) is written from a monotheistic perspective, the only resolution is to translate according to the Trinitarian position--which is monotheistic.  Otherwise, you're left with pantheism (an error) or a malicious lie.

@MikealSangrey - The Word was a divine God as the Son of God not the main God Himself.

@JoshuaB And so, out of thin air, you have to create demigods to keep your non-trinitarian position.  Your translation should say that--"...and the Word was himself a demigod."  Demigods do not exist.  So, let me head off something before you reply.  The Genesis 6 account of "Sons of God" refers to very powerful, male human beings.  Gods (more than one) can't breed with human beings; they don't have the plumbing.  The point of Genesis 6 is to highlight how far humanity had fallen such that a woman of any class was just a sexual object exploited by the powerful.

Mike, every son of God is "a god". Jesus said that "you are gods, all of you, sons of the Most High". Jesus is saying that a son of God is "a god" himself. Do you understand this?

Mike, Genesis 6 "sons of God" were rebellious fallen angels of Satan who had intercourse with human women and produced abominable giant offspring called "Nephilim". 1 Peter and Jude confirm this. And yes, all angels are male "sons of God" and do have genital plumbing.

Here is what Jesus stated at John 5:37, "And the Father Himself, who sent Me, has testified of Me. You have neither heard His voice at any time, nor seen His form."
And John 6:46, "Not that any man hath seen the Father, except he who is from God, he hath seen the Father." 1 Timothy 6:15-16, "Our Lord Jesus Christ, who at the due will be revealed by God, the blessed and only Ruler of all the King of kings and Lord of lords, vs16, who alone is immortal, whose home is in inaccessible light, whom no man has seen and no man is able to see; to him be honor and everlasting power."
One more! 1 John 4:12, "No one has seen God at any time. If we love one another, God abides in us, and His love has been perfected in us." Obviously it is God the Father who cannot be seen.
You want more proof you ask? How about at John 14, starting at vs8  where Philip said to Him, "Lord, show us the Father, and it is enough for us." Vs9, Jesus said to him. Have I been so long with you and yet you have not come to know Me, Philip? He who has seen Me  has seen the Father; how do you say, show us the Father?"
Vs9 is "NOT" teaching that Jesus Christ is God the Father. Jesus is pointing out that the Father has no separate manifestation from the Son. The Son is the only manifestation and revelation of the Father. What is know of the Father is revealed through the Son. to see the Son is to see the essence of the Father. (John 1:1,18; 10:30; 12;45; Colossians 1:15; Hebrews 1:3).
You also said the following: "In the OT, the Angel of the Lord was clearly the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ as God's Son, who wields the Tetragrammaton as the divine agent and mediator between God and man.
Seeing the Angel of the Lord was like seeing God, because Christ is the exact imprint of God's nature as the Image of God despite not being God Himself."
No, seeing the Angel of the Lord is seeing God. And it is based on what I already stated from John 14 and at Genesis 22:15-18. "Then the angel of the Lord called to Abraham a second time from heaven."
Vs16, "and said, "By Myself I have sworn, declares the Lord, because you have done this thing, and have not withheld your only son, Vs17, indeed I will greatly multiply your seed as the stars of the heavens, and as the sand which is on the seashore; and you shall possess the gate of their enemies."
Vs18, "And in your seed all the nations of the earth shall be blessed, because you have "OBEYED MY VOICE." Who's voice, the angel of the Lords' voice."
Now, an actual angel cannot swear an oath on behalf of God Himself. But the angel of the Lord can because He's the Son of God His Father and has the Father's nature/essence.
Hebrews 6:13-16, "For when God made the promise to Abraham, since He could swear by no one greater, HE SWORE BY HIMSELF, vs14, "saying. I will surely bless you, and I will surely multiply you." Vs15"And thus, having patiently waited, he obtained the promise. Vs16, "For men swear by one greater than themselves, and with them an oath given as confirmation is an end of every dispute." I almost forgot to address what you stated about Jacob.
How about what Hagar said about the angel of the Lord at Genesis 16 starting at vs7. "Now the angel of the Lord found her by a spring of water in the wilderness, by the spring on the way to Shur." (I'm going to summarize this.)
Vs9, "Then the angel of the Lord  said to Hagar to return to her mistress Sari. Vs10, "Moreover, the angel of the Lord said to her, "I will greatly multiply your descendants so that they shall be too many to count." At vs11 "TAOTL told her she is with child and will bear a son and his name will be Ishmael." Today, these are the Arabs.
At vs13 Hagar says, "The she called the name off the Lord who spoke to her, "Thou art a God who sees" for she said, "Have I even remained alive here after seeing Him?"
Moving on to Genesis 17:1-3, "Now when Abram was ninety-nine years old, the Lord appeared to Abram and said to him. "I am God Almighty; Walk before Me, and be blameless. vs2, "And I will establish My covenant between Me and you, And I will multiply you exceedingly. Vs3, And Abram fell on his face, and God talked with him, saying etc.
So here's the question? Is the being who multiplied Hagar's descendants the same being who multiply Abram's descendants here at Genesis 17? Btw, the Lord God Almighty physically appeared to Abram. This is verified at Genesis 17:22.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The "problem" asked by the OP is more wide-spread than the question supposes.   We observe the clear statement several times in the Bible that no human has ever seen God the Father:

John 1:18 - No one has ever seen God; the only God, who is at the Father’s side, he has made him known.
John 5:37 - You have never heard His voice nor seen His form
John 6:46 - No one has seen the Father except the one who is from God; only he has seen the Father. (See also Matt 18:10.)
1 John 4:12 - No one has ever seen God; but if we love one another, God remains in us, and His love is perfected in us.
1 Tim 1:17 - Now to the King eternal, immortal, invisible, the only God …
1 Tim 6:16 - He alone is immortal and dwells in unapproachable light. No one has ever seen Him, nor can anyone see Him.
Col 1:15 - … the invisible God …
Ex 33:20 - But He added, “You cannot see My face, for no one can see Me and live.”
Isa 45:15 - Truly You are a God who hides Himself, O God of Israel, the Saviour.

By contrast, we have many texts saying that people have seen God.

Isa 64:4 - From ancient times no one has heard, no ear has perceived, no eye has seen any God besides You, who acts on behalf of those who wait for Him.
Job 42:5 - My ears had heard of You [= the LORD, V1], but now my eyes have seen You.
Gen 18:1, 10 - Then the LORD appeared to Abraham by the Oaks of Mamre in the heat of the day, while he was sitting at the entrance of his tent. ... Then the LORD said, “I will surely return to you at this time next year, and your wife Sarah will have a son!”
Gen 32:30 - So Jacob called the place Peniel, saying, “It is because I saw God face to face, and yet my life was spared.”
Ex 3:5, 6 - “Do not come any closer,” God said. “Take off your sandals, for the place where you are standing is holy ground.” Then He said, “I am the God of your father, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob.”
Josh 5:13 - 6:2 - And the LORD said to Joshua, “Behold, I have delivered Jericho into your hand, along with its king and its mighty men of valour.” (V2)
Judges 6:14 - The LORD turned to him and said, “Go in the strength you have and save Israel from the hand of Midian. Am I not sending you?” [See also V16]
Judges 16:22 - “We are going to die,” he said to his wife, “for we have seen God!”
Eze 1 - the prophet's vision of God; many elements of which are repeated in Rev 4 & 5.  Further, we find in Eze 10:4, “the radiance of the glory of the LORD.” And in Heb 1:3, “The Son is the radiance of God’s glory and the exact representation of his being.”
See also instances of the “Angel of the LORD” clearly being the LORD - Gen 16:7-13, 22:11-17, 32:24-30, 48:16, Ex 3:2-6, 32:34, Num 22:22-35, Josh 5:13-15, Judg 2:1-4, 6:11-23, 13:3-23, Isa 63:9, Dan 3:25, 28, Hos 12:4, 5, Zech 3:1-7, Mal 3:1, Rev 8:3-5, 10:1-10, 18:1, 20:1-4.
A closely related phrase, “Angel of God” who is clearly God as in Gen 6:13, 8:15, 9:8, 17, 15:13, 17:3, 4, 21:12, 16-21, 35:1, 10, Ex 4:3-8, 6:2, 23:20, 21 , Deut 1:6, 1 Kings 12:22, etc.  See also Acts 10:3, 4, Gal 4:14.

The very fact that the NT so confidently asserts that no human has seen God the Father, but many people have seen God/YHWH in the OT means the inescapable conclusion is such epiphanies were of the pre-incarnate Jesus as per John 8:58 – “Truly, truly, I tell you,” Jesus declared, “before Abraham was born, I am!”
Indeed, it appears that the main focus of the OT was the pre-incarnate Christ, with a few important exceptions.  In fact, the Gospel of John actually says this:

John 1:18 – No one has ever seen God [the Father]; the unique God, the
One in the bosom of the Father, He has made Him known.

Thus, taking this verse as it reads suggests that the “Father” was essentially unknown before Jesus revealed Him.  This confirms the statement in Isa 9:6 that the Messiah (the future “Jesus”) was the One known as the “Father” in the OT.

Dottard, your translation of John 1:18 is faulty. The Greek says, "No one has ever seen God, unless the only begotten Son, who is at the Father’s side, reveals Him." Also, the Angel of the LORD as the pre-incarnate Son was the mediator between the one God and man. He spoke on behalf of God despite not being God Himself, hence why the fathers could "see God" despite not actually seeing God. Do you understand this Dottard?

The fulness of God at vs16 could not be known through any ordinary man. It must come through the One who possess the nature of God. God's nature cannot be seen  to others by any ordinary man. The utter inability of no man is stressed in opposition to God who revealed himself in the Only Begotten. In the bosom of the Father refers to the truth of His deity and shows the reason the only begotten Son of God could be the full revelation of all that God is. The Son is God's interpreter. God did not entrust His full  revelation to be given by men; He took the initiative to declare it for Himself.

@JoshuaB - My translation is accurate - yours is faulty for the following reasons:  There is no "unless" in the Greek; the word "begotten" is not in the text; "side" is not in the text; the word "revealed" is in the aorist tense and so cannot be "reveals" but must be "revealed"; the best MSS have "God" and not "Son".

@Mr.Bond - I fully agree.

Dangerous ground, to state that 'Messiah' is the same person as 'Father' (if, indeed, that it was what you are doing). God was a 'father' to Israel but only in a very limited way. The revelation of the Father, as you state elsewhere, is dependent on the coming of the Son (a more accurate statement).

@Mr.Bond Yes, indeed. The only begotten,(monogenes) who is in the bosom of the Father - once manifested in humanity - reveals the Father. Otherwise, man remains in darkness for no man (in his own nature, unborn again) can 'see' God.

@Mr. Bond   ummm a bunch of opinion couched as fact. simply stating something you believe is not evidence.

@ACME https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/84390/21426

@nigel     busted, lol   however there is some fact to support my supposition.......
